# How to structure related pull requests

Tags: git, github, github-codereviews

I'm working on a large section of a web app and have a several jira tickets assigned to me to complete it step by step: e.g.

- Task 1: create the main page of the section displaying a list of items
- Task 2: create a page with detailed item description
- Task 3: add create/edit/delete buttons on the detailed page to perform CRUD operations
- ...

So in terms of jira tickets everything's clear, but how should I organize the work with github pull request (PR) system if each task somehow depends on the previous?

E.g. I've made a new branch for Task 1, finished it and created a PR. Then started working on the Task 2: created a new branch, based on Task 1 branch, finished work and now I have to create another PR, but what should be the target branch? If I choose dev, the PR would include contents of the Task 1 (which makes review difficult and doesn't seem right). Maybe I should wait for the first PR to be merged and only then start working on Task 2 (but then all work stops until Task 1 is merged)?

Another problematic situation I've encountered: let's say at the end of the sprint management decides that we no longer need the list page in our app (Task 1), detailed page is enough (Tasks 2 and later). And those two PRs are still in code review and Task 2 is based on Task 1 branch. What should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This is my *personal* way to handle this: You stack one branch after the other, you set as the target branch the real target branch, not the branch that each ticket was started from. When you create the PRs, then as you have more tickets one on top of the other it will be more difficult to see what each ticket is about. You *might* set the target branch as the branch that you started working from *but* you have to be careful to change the target branch later on when those branches start to get merged so that when you merge the child branches, they do not end up being merged into another PRs branch and then get lost.

Now, this is manageable, but it's not *trivial* in terms of moving branches around. Say you work on ticket1, started from master... you are done... then you start ticket2 from ticket1... and you are done.... now you start ticket3 from ticket 2.... and you are done.

Then you realize that you need to do something on ticket2, how do you proceed? You can change ticket2... then what happens with ticket3? Specially if you want to get the changes form ticket2 into ticke3. Then you can just rebase ticket3 on top of ticket2, andf it should be it.

How about if a change is required on ticket1? Same thing, you need the change to be pulled into ticket2 and ticket3. How do you proceed? The simplest route? rebase ticket3 on **ticket1**, then find where ticket2 has to be and place the branch there.

This is so simple because you are moving branches *in sync*, but it can be much trickier if the base branch belongs to someone else.... what happens if the person rebases the branch? Will you just ask to rebase? You can't *just* do it because you are not responsible for the revisions of the branch that you started working from.... in fact, if you rebase that, you might end up bringing stuff that was removed from the base branch altogether without you noticing. See? It's manageable, but not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

There are *various* options for answering this question...

I create all branches from the `develop`-branch, and after pull request I merge all branches back to develop, that this `develop`-branch is the *main*-branch!

Create e.g for task 1 branch A based on develop branch. Make the changes that need to be made in this branch, push it to github and create there a pull request. Now, when you want to continue working, create branch 2 for e.g. task 2, based on branch 1. So do not checkout to develop-branch. Branch A is waiting to be approved. If branch A approved and merged back to develop-branch, branch B based on develop-branch and no longer on branch A, because this were merged back into develop branch.

So you can create pull requests and work further with creating new branches, without loss any code, because each branch is based on the previous branch.